# How to use mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

Here's a copy of my code:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml"); ?>
<?php echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"; ?>

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "database_user", "database_pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error()); 

$cityquery = "SELECT * FROM cities ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$cityresult = mysql_query($cityquery);
$cityrow = mysql_fetch_row($cityresult);
$city = $cityrow[0];

$servicequery = "SELECT * FROM services ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$serviceresult = mysql_query($servicequery);
$servicerow = mysql_fetch_row($serviceresult);
$service = $servicerow[0];
?>

<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>Website Name</title>
  <link>http://www.mywebsite.com</link>
  <description>This is the main description.</description>
  <pubDate><?echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s');?></pubDate>

<?php foreach( range( 1, 25 ) as $i ): ?>

<item>
    <title><?php echo $service; ?> in <?php echo $city; ?></title>
    <pubDate><?echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s');?></pubDate>
    <link>http://www.mywebsite.com</link>
    <description>This is where the description goes.</description>
</item>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</channel>
</rss>
```

I am trying to generate an RSS feed that has 25 items in.  Right now all 25 items show the exact same thing.

You can see the code for the title of each item here that is what's causing the problem:

```
<title><?php echo $service; ?> in <?php echo $city; ?></title>
```

What this is doing is pulling a list of random services and random cities from my MySQL database.  Each item's title should display a random city and random title.  But as of right now, they are all showing the same city and same service for all 25 rss feed items.

This may be something simple but I feel like I'm staring at a brick wall because I've been working on this all day and haven't been able to figure it out.  I believe that mysql_fetch_array may need to be used, but I can't seem to get it right.  I would really appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: *"How to use mysql_fetch_array?"* - **don't**, it's deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are fetching the next row only once, so it will always contain the same data.

Aside the fact that it's deprecated as mentioned by @Phil in a comment, you should fetch a new row each time in your loop.

Edit: the code below should do what you expect

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "database_user", "database_pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error()); 

$cityquery = "SELECT * FROM cities ORDER BY RAND()";
$cityresult = mysql_query($cityquery);

$servicequery = "SELECT * FROM services ORDER BY RAND()";
$serviceresult = mysql_query($servicequery);
?>

<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>Website Name</title>
  <link>http://www.mywebsite.com</link>
  <description>This is the main description.</description>
  <pubDate><?echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s');?></pubDate>

<?php foreach( range( 1, 25 ) as $i ):
    $cityrow = mysql_fetch_row($cityresult);
    $city = $cityrow[0];
    $servicerow = mysql_fetch_row($serviceresult);
    $service = $servicerow[0];
?>

<item>
    <title><?php echo $service; ?> in <?php echo $city; ?></title>
    <pubDate><?echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s');?></pubDate>
    <link>http://www.mywebsite.com</link>
    <description>This is where the description goes.</description>
</item>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_row()` fetch a row from the result set as an array of numeric keys, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will do the same but use the selected field names as keys, and `mysql_fetch_array()` will do both at once (by default) or optionally can receive a parameter to specify if you want it either in numeric or associative format.

It has nothing to do with the solution.

What you are missing here is the fact that you must call `mysql_fetch_row()` for each record you are selecting from the database. This function should be called in a loop until it returns `FALSE`.

Instead, you are calling it only once, and printing the same result 25 times.

In addition, you are selecting only one record from the database anyway (`SELECT ... LIMIT 1`) how do you expect to have 25 different results?

Comment: Good catch with the `LIMIT 1`, I hadn't seen that when I wrote my answer.